# Unable to install MySQL ODBC connectors in Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, 64-bit, mysql, connector, odbc

Upon following the instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a), which links [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/), and installing the latest version (8.0.30) ODBC connector, I still receive the following unhelpful error message when selecting Data -> Get Data -> From Database -> From MySQL Database:

> This connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used.

I have restarted Excel and the machine multiple times.  I have tried installing the 32-bit and 64-bit connectors.  I have tried installing from the standalone MSI and the MySQL Installer application.  I have even tried installing the ADO.NET connector as well, as quizzically suggested [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/installed-mysql-connector-net-8-0-13-but-still-doesnt-connect-in/m-p/297717).  I have tried looking in the Event Viewer for application errors.  Any suggestions are appreciated, as I'm out of ideas.

Running Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2206 Build 16.0.15330.20260) 64-bit  under Windows 11.

UPDATE:  [More people with the same problem over on Microsoft forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/issue-with-the-mysql-odbc-driver-for-microsoft/fa2f3c9f-7b24-4045-951e-396013c31d22).

Comment: Have you downloaded the 64-bit connector?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit connectors.

Comment: As a workaround, can you create an ODBC Data Source using the driver (search ODBC in start menu)? Then in Excel: Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From ODBC

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thanks, I had noticed that still worked.  It's very kludgy and in particular, less well-suited for the inexperienced users I'm working with.

Comment: Is it a Windows 11 compatibility issue?

Comment: @Lee maybe?  If only something were being logged somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I headed over the MySQL bug tracker and found this one:  [MySQL Bugs: #107316: MySQL 8.0.29 introduces a bug which prevents use of the Connector software](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107316)

Based on that, and the [hidden documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/mysqldatabase#prerequisites) to additionally install the ADO.NET connector, I've finally got this working with 64-bit Excel 365 by installing the [64-bit ODBC Connector, version 8.0.28](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-odbc/), and the [32-bit ADO.NET connector, version 8.0.28](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/).

Note that there is only a 32-bit ADO.NET connector available.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the Microsoft documentation links to the generic MySql ODBC Connectors page, which at the time of writing is listing the connectors at version `8.0.30`.

However, I found that only the older GA versions of the connectors work with my version of Excel

> Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20166)
> 32-bit

The versions that worked for me are `5.3.14`.
In my case I installed both, but since my Excel is 32Bit I guess only the 32-Bit/x86 connector was required. In your case I'd install the 64-Bit/x64 connectors. To play it safe installing both should be fine.

- [Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer - 5.3.14](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=491747)
- [Windows (x64, 64-bit), MSI Installer - 5.3.14](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=491748)